# Invalidating BASIC login-config does not show relogin prompt

Tags: jsf, httpsession, invalidation

I am trying to create a simple authentication with jsf. I can login with BASIC login-config but the session seems can not invalidated and the session persist. This is the bean to handle logout:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="security")
public class SecurityController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityController.class);
    public SecurityController() {
    }
    public String logout() {
        logger.error(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        logger.error(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        return "users?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

The console shows these messages:

```
00:08:32,478 WARN  [com.jsf.bean.SecurityController] (default task-14) admin
00:08:32,479 WARN  [com.jsf.bean.SecurityController] (default task-14) admin
```

I think the `invalidateSession()` does not working since the user still exists.

**EDIT**

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="security")
public class SecurityController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityController.class);
    public SecurityController() {
    }
    public String logout() {
        //Before
        HttpSession sessionbefore = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        logger.warn("ID: " + sessionbefore.getId());

        //Invalidating
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();

        // After
        HttpSession sessionafter = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        logger.warn("ID: " + sessionafter.getId());//java.lang.NullPointerException
        return "users?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare session ID before and after invalidating. It shows null pointer exception. So I think the session invalidating is works.
I am expected to get relogin prompt after logout. But it would not, I still can access my web after logout.

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>loggedin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ROLE_LOGISTICS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>RealmUsersRoles</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>ROLE_LOGISTICS</role-name>
</security-role>
```

This logout button to call the logout bean:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="logout" action="#{security.logout()}"></h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work? Did you compare sessionID's? 1000% sure it is the same session in the new request?

Comment: Basic authentication cannot be invalidated by removing the session. It works outside of the session and the browser will automagically login again if the server requests a basic authentication login... Totally not jsf related but plain web based development (not even java/web specific)

Comment: thank you @Kukeltje

Comment: No, because the browser already has a username/password for this site